# PlotShape - {{price}} - PineScript - V5

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5

I wrote a trailing stop loss script. I want the code to display the price where the stoploss was hit.
[image]

But it is displaying {{Price}} as a string, and not the actual number of the bar where the stoploss was hit.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with the `plotshape()` function. It expects a `const string`, which means the value must be known at compile time.

You can use `label` instead.

Example from [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#drawings). It will plot the bar index and high price.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)
label.new(bar_index, high, style=label.style_none,
          text="x=" + tostring(bar_index) + "\ny=" + tostring(high))
```

[image]